# Is it possible to integrate ionic into bootstrap template and make them work?

Tags: angular, templates, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4, integration

I would like to purchase a bootstrap template like Sparker:

https://themeforest.net/item/sparker-directory-and-listings-template/22716006

and integrate angular and ionic into it.

I want this template to serve me as web app as well as mobile apps.

Do you think this bootstrap + ionic combination will work?

Are there any points for not doing this?

Do you think it would be a better idea to purchase a template for web app and one
separate ionic template?

Answer (score 0):

It will have style issues, absolutely!

If you want to use web templates you can try to buy Angular themes but not HTML & CSS.

i **recommend** to use ionic theme if you don't want to work on HTML content

https://ionicthemes.com/

Comment: The thing is that I have found only Angular admin templates and I need something like this: 
http://preview.themeforest.net/item/sparker-directory-and-listings-template/full_screen_preview/22716006?_ga=2.117691337.1173142078.1576343193-305983891.1561277293

but I didn't find any like this, only admin which are not suitable for me. 

I will buy an Ionic template for the mobiles, but for web they don't seem to look as a professional website.

Comment: Well, for that i think you need to build user interface by yourself.